# Unicode input dangers

Tags: security, gwt, unicode, input

Are there any real dangers to user-input unicode, that isn't handled by user agent / browser, etc?

Obviously from server to client, there's a real threat of spoofing, but i'm trying to figure out what concrete 'attacks' (if any) or grievances i should be aware when treating unicode input.

The question is language agnostic, but i am making this question having in mind the security implications on a GWT application.

Comment: *Outputting* user controlled unicode strings can be very problematic. But I don't see many issues with input.

Comment: What kind of issues would you find problematic with outputting user controlled unicode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of several issues with user controlled unicode strings:

1. There are multiple ways to express equivalent strings in unicode. For example `ä` can be expressed as single codepoint, or as `a` followed by a combining `¨`. Unicode normalization helps against most of these issues.
2. There are characters which allow strange caret movements. I've heard of a chat where you could place your message over somebody else's message. Which got them banned for saying inappropriate things, because the admins didn't realize who actually sent said message.
3. There are look alike characters. For example there are some Russian or Greek characters that are optically indistinguishable from their ASCII equivalents. That's very problematic of a string should uniquely identify something. For example usernames or domains. Similar to the classical `l` vs `I` problem, except much worse.
4. With UTF-8 and UTF-16, splitting a string in the middle of a codepoint might cause some issues.
5. Some operations on a string might change its lengths unexpectedly. For example uppercasing a string might make it longer.

There are probably more issues, I'm certainly no expert on unicode

Comment: 1. That's not really a "danger", just something to consider. If 4. is an issue, you're just not handling strings/encodings correctly. 5. That's something to consider, whether that's a "danger" very much depends how low-level your language is. I'd agree that 2. and 3. are points that may cause problems for users.

Comment: Which brings me to a follow up question, how many of these issues are already dealt with internally by a language / framework like GWT? (I'm thinking of unicode normalization for instance)

Comment: There are likely helper functions, but you still need to be aware of most of these issues. They can't be solved automagically.

Comment: I'd emphasize that the number of 8-bit bytes or 16-bit words ≠ the number of code points, the number of code points ≠ the number of glyphs/characters/etc. Miscalculating and mixing up these things can lead to buffer overflows (and all kinds of nasty things) and to data disclosure (e.g. stale buffer data may not be fully overwritten by the user input). Also, the input can be malformed, that is, contain invalid code points or just be invalid in terms of UTF8/16 encoding. The code must be able to deal with this.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest danger with any user input is using that input in a context that has "special characters". I.e., naïvely concatenating it into SQL queries or outputting it into HTML. If part of your application's behavior is controlled by strings (like SQL queries or HTML pages) and the user has control over these strings and can inject his own commands, that's a danger.

There's nothing special about Unicode over other encodings in this regard though. The special characters in your environment are well defined, all you need to do is escape, filter or sanitize any user input so it renders these special characters non-special. This is the same you need to do for any other encoding as well. You need to take care that your escaping/filtering/sanitization functions are aware of the correct encoding so they can do their job properly.

Apart from that, Unicode encoded text is just text. When you neuter any special characters it contains and handle the encoding properly otherwise, there's no danger in just text. Apart from your users sbuıɥʇ pɹıǝʍ buıʇıɹʍ or exploiting lookalike characters for some specific purpose, but that's not about generalized dangers anymore.